# Stakeholder unable to log-in VSTS in our Organization

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I am VSTS administrator in our organization. I have done recently migrated TFS 2018 update 2 to VSTS instance.

Some "Stakeholders" try to login VSTS URL:https://XXXX.visualstudio.com[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdi7v.png)

It is going to like : *Your name:
                      * We'll reach you at
                      *From(United States)
                          "Continue"
        After that window: -> " host my projects atXXXXXXXXXX.visualstudio.com

Can anyone suggest look into this?
(When A stackholder trying to access VSTS, the site is asking him to host Projects)enter image description here

it is redirecting to host my projects.
And

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jylW2.png)

Comment: Does the issue still occur after they updated their profile? Did you check if they are listed in your VSTS users?

Comment: I have checked the list of users in VSTS, The users are there in the group. I am not sure about the updating the profile, Can you let me know the process to do it?

Comment: Do they still get the "Host my projects" dialog now when access to your VSTS account?

Comment: What's the result after clicking continue button (your screenshot)?